# How to set .xml file as playlist in wimpy player?

Tags: xml, mp3, audio-player

How can I put `.xml` playlist in wimpy player, my codes works for single MP3 as below:

```
<div id="MyTarget">

<script>

// Create a "new" wimpy player and set the "target" option 
// to match the Target Element's "id".
var myPlayer = new wimpyPlayer({
Target: "MyTarget",           
media: "../ppa/1/101/song1.mp3",
skin: "/play/wimpy.skins/038.tsv",
startUpText : "hello" 

});

</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same code you have, but rather than setting the "media" option to an MP3 file, set the URL to an XML file:

```
media: "/path/to/playlist.xml",
```

Wimpy also lets you incorporate Javascript directly into the "media" option. So you can have a javascript playlist as:

```
<!-- The DIV to put wimpy into -->
<div id="MyTarget"></div>

<script>

// A javascript playlist:
var playlist = [
    {
        file : "../song1.mp3",
        title : "Song One"
    },

    {
        file : "../song2.mp3",
        title : "Song Two",
    }
];

// Create the player
var myPlayer = new wimpyPlayer({
            target      : "MyTarget",           
            media       : playlist, // Setting the javascript "playlist" var here
            startUpText : "hello" 
});
</script>
```